# How to fix the width of any column when creating a table?

Tags: java2word

I'm trying to put a 2 columns table in a new MSWord document using [java2word](https://github.com/leonardoanalista/java2word) but I'm unable to fix the width of the columns. 
Here the code:

```
Table tbl = new Table();
tbl.addTableEle(TableEle.TH, "Descriptions", "");
tbl.setRepeatTableHeaderOnEveryPage();
tbl.addTableEle(TableEle.TD, "Description",   "cette case sert à afficher les détails");
tbl.addTableEle(TableEle.TD, "pers appelées", "Marc, Stéphane, Bernard");
tbl.addTableEle(TableEle.TD, "liste",         "vide pour l'instant");
tbl.addTableEle(TableEle.TD, "Fonctions",     "Chef, administrateur, employé");
tbl.addTableEle(TableEle.TD, "code",          "select * from personne");
myDoc.addEle(tbl);
myDoc.addEle(new BreakLine(2));
```

I would like to set the width of the 1th column to [3 cm], and also make the 1th column unwrappable (doesn't split the row in 2 rows).

Is anybody can help ?

Comment: Ok, forget my question, I've updated the classes TableHeader, TableCol and finally Table to take the size of columns as args in the constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new code look like this now:

```
Table tbl = new Table(3.0f, 14.0f); //Sizes of the columns in cm
tbl.addTableEle(TableEle.TH, "Descriptions", "");
tbl.setRepeatTableHeaderOnEveryPage();
tbl.addTableEle(TableEle.TD, "Description",   "cette case sert à afficher les détails");
tbl.addTableEle(TableEle.TD, "pers appelées", "Marc, Stéphane, Bernard");
tbl.addTableEle(TableEle.TD, "liste",         "vide pour l'instant");
tbl.addTableEle(TableEle.TD, "Fonctions",     "Chef, administrateur, employé");
tbl.addTableEle(TableEle.TD, "code",          "select * from personne");
myDoc.addEle(tbl);
myDoc.addEle(new BreakLine(2));
```